# Is there a way to validate the whole JSON response using SOAPUI?

Tags: json, automation, soapui, jsonpath, assertion

I tried using "COntains" option in SoapUI but it is not working so I tried Jsonpath ut I can't figure out how to.

Previously when I did XML request, I just use "COntains" and copy the whole response on the assertion.
But I cannot find to wor on it on JSON.

Comment: Any success, does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SOAPUI suggests to use [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to [validate responses](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/validating-messages/validating-json-messages/).

To match an entire document you could simply search for the root `$`
[image]

and match it against the entire document (special formatting might throw a wrench here).